# ¿Cómo generar numero incremental en sql server 2008, C# o JQuery?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola a todos tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Quiero hacer un número correlativo y que aumente de 1 en 1 como por ejemplo `identity(1,1)` pero en este caso con este formato TCK000000001 si se pudiese en sql o sino también un método en Jquery o C# que me permita generar un número correlativo y poder insertarlo en la base de datos.

Tabla Ticket

```
create table tb_ticket
(
num_ticket varchar(20) primary key not null,
desc_ticket varchar(500),
Especialista varchar(20)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Al menos desde la versión 2008, dispones de columnas calculadas. Si te sirve el `identity` como numerador, puedes reformular la columna del número de la siguiente forma:

```
create table tb_ticket
(
  id int identity,
  num_ticket as 'TK' +  right('00000000' + convert(varchar, id), 8),
  desc_ticket varchar(500),
  Especialista varchar(20)
);
```

En este caso `num_ticket` es una columna virtual, no existe físicamente, se calcula  al vuelo cuando la necesites. No olvides que el `identity` tiene algunas limitaciones como numerador: a) Las transacciones que se deshace pueden terminar dejando huecos b) hay un feo comportamiento del motor ante ciertos reinicios en se pueden generar huecos de mayor tamaño.